# initializing transitionMatrix in kalman filter

Tags: matrix, filter, transition, kalman-filter

I am working on a object tracking project and I want to improve the results I am getting using a Kalman filter.

```
KalmanFilter KF(4 , 2 , 2 ,CV_32F );
Mat_<float> state(4, 1);
Mat_<float> processNoise(4, 1, CV_32F);
Mat_<float> measurement(2 , 1 , CV_32F); 
measurement.setTo(Scalar(0));

KF.statePre.at<float>(0) = 0;
KF.statePre.at<float>(1) = 0;
KF.statePre.at<float>(2) = 0;
KF.statePre.at<float>(3) = 0;

KF.transitionMatrix = *(Mat_<float>(4, 4) << 1,0,1,0,   0,1,0,1,  0,0,1,0,  0,0,0,1); //Including velocity
```

in last line,we have error "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Project(Kalman).exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Project(Kalman).exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Project(Kalman).exe has focus."
please help me :(

Answer (score 1):

const float transition[2][2] = { 1, 1, 0, 1} ;
memcpy(KF.transitionMatrix.data , transition , sizeof(transition) ) ;